# How to make main method of a class wait on GUI actionPerformed

Tags: user-interface, wait, notify

I am using a while loop in the main method of one class that continuously prompts the user to enter a name, then opens a new window (created with a separate class I wrote that extends Panel) and allows them to choose from people with that last name.

However, once the main method opens the new window with the list of names, it continues to run  and restarts the loop, prompting the user to type in a new last name before they can even select one from the last loop.

How do I pause the while loop after it opens the list window until the user has selected a name and the window closes?

I have tried using wait and notify logic, but do not know how to implement a wait statement in the loop that will wait for a notify statement in a different class.

This code does not work in its current form, but this is where I want to code to wait and then where I want the actionPerformed clause once the button is pressed to notify it to continue.

The class SelectListener is in the class DoctorPanel, which extends Panel and is used to create the Frame.

```
package components;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Runner2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Doctor> fullList=new ArrayList<Doctor>();
    fullList.add(new Doctor("John","Smith","High Point","NC",27031,"Eye Doctor","202 Fake St."));
    fullList.add(new Doctor("Mark","Smith","Kernersville","NC",27023,"The Place","222 Apple St."));
    fullList.add(new Doctor("Billy","Smith","Winston-Salem","NC",27345,"Eye Associates","8275 Farmview Ave."));
    fullList.add(new Doctor("John","Baker","Lewisville","NC",27678,"Eye Care","929 Pilot Cir."));
    fullList.add(new Doctor("Wes","Baker","Mocksville","NC",27324,"Endocrinologist","435 Fun Ln."));

    ArrayList<Doctor> selectedList=new ArrayList<Doctor>();

    while(true){
        String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last name of doctor (or 'done' if finished).");
        if (name.equals("done"))
            break;

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        DoctorPanel panel = new DoctorPanel(name,fullList);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        wait();
        selectedList.add(panel.getDoctorAt(panel.getDoctor()));
        frame.dispose();
        //System.out.println(panel.getDoctor());

    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}


class SelectListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int index=list.getSelectedIndex();
        DOCTOR=index;
        //System.out.println(DOCTOR);
        notify();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change from

```
 JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    DoctorPanel panel = new DoctorPanel(name,fullList);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    wait();
    selectedList.add(panel.getDoctorAt(panel.getDoctor()));
    frame.dispose();
    //System.out.println(panel.getDoctor());
```

to

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    DoctorPanel panel = new DoctorPanel(name,fullList);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    if(your_boolean) {
        wait();
        selectedList.add(panel.getDoctorAt(panel.getDoctor()));
        frame.dispose();
        //System.out.println(panel.getDoctor());
   }
```

That way you can pause by having your_boolean equal to false and in the action listener set your_boolean to true;